# .htaccess Check for file in two locations, otherwise throw 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The way my site is currently structured, the actual site is in its own separate folder. Here's what I mean:

```
 /projects
 /files
 /pictures
 /tools
 /school
 /~webroot
 .htaccess
```

This makes the file-system much easier to manage and navigate. An easy way to utilize this, without having everyone navigate to `http://domain.com/~webroot/`, and still allow them to access files and such like `http://domain.com/projects/`, is to use the `htaccess` I wrote below to check for files in both the real root, and ~webroot directories.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~webroot/$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /~webroot/index.php [L,QSA]
```

However, if the file doesn't exist anywhere (root or ~webroot), an HTTP 500 error is thrown instead of an HTTP 404. In order to display my 404 error page, I have to instead use these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/~webroot/$0 !-F
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.shtml [B,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/~webroot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~webroot/$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /~webroot/index.php [L,QSA]
```

This is all *quite* messy, and it's only a trick and doesn't actually throw an HTTP 404, which keeps 404s from being documented using my statistics application. Is there a way to: Check if file exists in root, if not check if file exists in ~webroot, if not throw real HTTP 404 error?

I do also have all my `ErrorDocument`'s defined properly.

Comment: Oh, thank you for explaining the B flag. I had seen it before, but never thought to ask about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this was a while ago, but wanted to chime in. For a rewrite rule to hit a 404, I always use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

I'm not sure if it's correct, but it works for me. I'm pretty sure it should always be with "L" to prevent further rewriting.

BTW, what is the "B" flag for? I only know the ones listed on the apache mod_rewrite page, so I'm lost on it's meaning.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

EDIT: ah, my problem is I look at older version docs. Thank you, Swivelgames. I probably would have never even known I was looking at the older docs if you hadn't pointed that out (need to update my bookmarks).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: `[B]` is for escaping back references. It escapes all non-alphanumeric characters. It's most useful for concatenating referenced text onto a query string, like so: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?myVar=$1` That will make sure the referenced data only acts as the value of myVar and not a separate key-value pair, where if the reference were to contain "&foo=bar" or something similar.

Comment: I was still looking for an answer, so I'm glad you answered. The answer seems so obvious! Thanks so much. It worked perfectly. I'm surprised I wasn't able to think of that. And, the B flag was carried over from one of my other .htaccess files, so I just replaced it with the R=404 flag. Thanks a whole lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your 404 page a PHP file, you can add this before any output to get real 404's:

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); ?>
```

This will cause PHP to trigger a 'real' 404 (from the browsers point of view) which gets passed back to the browser. If your statistics package is internal to your server this approach may or may not work, I'm not sure.

The only other solution I can think of is to redirect to a non-existent file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/non-existent-404-generator
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/~webroot/$0 !-F
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /non-existent-404-generator [B,L]
```

Comment: Indeed. This is what I just implemented about 10 minutes ago, but I just wanted to see if there was a different way to do it using htaccess. I'm not sure if its logging the 404s yet, though, as it's almost too early to tell. Thanks Matthew, I hope it works.

Comment: @Swivelgames I believe the only way to trigger a 404 internally in the server via mod_rewrite is to do an internal rewrite to a file that is reasonably guaranteed to not exist.

Comment: The problem with doing this, as I stated in the OP, is that, for some reason, a 500 error is thrown instead. I would assume because the way I'm currently doing it is possibly erroneous. It looks like it may be looping? If file doesn't exist, check in ~webroot, file doesn't exist, check in ~webroot, file doesn't exist, check in ~webroot, etc...

Comment: @Swivelgames: Check my updated version that should take care of looping, but I would have expected `[L]` to prevent that.

Comment: I redirect to a 404 and thought that was the only way to do it.